# Prahlada later got abusive about Vishnu

Tags: reference-request

The great Bhaktha Prahlada much later in life accused Vishnu during exchanges with Adi Parasakthi. This is attributed to his genetic nature being that of a Rakshas that took over his personalty. I read it in a Telugu book *Sri Devi Bhagavatham* by Mithili Venkateswara Rao, March 2017.

But is it true?  Does it have a mention in other sources or references?

Comment: 1. He's not a Rakshasa (he's a Daitya) 2. He didn't know it was Vishnu (he met Naranarayana) (then this happened again with Narasimha) 3. Both times he eventually, technically won, although not through force.

Comment: I requested for references of later events.